# How to send a payment request on Hedera with a recipient address and an amount?

Tags: javascript, payment, hedera-hashgraph

I hope you are doing well. Can someone advise me on the best method to send a payment request on Hedera with a recipient address and an amount? I am trying to create a QR code for a web app that can be scanned and understood in something like Hashpack. This is the best I have come up with so far:

```
const {
  Client,
  AccountId,
  PrivateKey,
  Hbar,
  PaymentRequest,
  PaymentRequestKind,
} = require("@hashgraph/sdk");

const client = Client.forMainnet();
const operatorId = AccountId.fromString(process.env.OPERATOR_ID);
const operatorKey = PrivateKey.fromString(process.env.OPERATOR_KEY);

async function sendPaymentRequest(recipientAddress, amount) {
  try {
    // Check if recipientAddress is defined
    if (!recipientAddress) {
      throw new Error("Recipient address is undefined");
    }

    // Set up the recipient account ID
    const recipientAccountId = AccountId.fromString(recipientAddress);

    // Create a payment request with the specified recipient and amount
    const paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest()
      .addTransfer(operatorId, recipientAccountId, Hbar.fromTinybars(amount))
      .setKind(PaymentRequestKind.EXACT_PAYMENT);

    // Sign the payment request with the operator's private key
    paymentRequest.sign(operatorKey);

    // Print the payment request string to the console
    console.log("Payment request: ", paymentRequest.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

sendPaymentRequest("0.0.419514", 1000000);
```